# Simple robocopy script to backup a harddrive not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, robocopy

I am trying to run robocopy to backup my whole harddrive

This what I have so far
robocopy f: G:\Backup\f\  /E /R:2 /ZB /DCOPY:T /SL

The problem I have is that I seem to be geting into a loop where is is following the shortcuts and copy that at well and for some reason on the win7 build they are looping untill the path length breaks.

Has anybody got line that wordk or can tell what switch I have wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
robocopy /E /R:1 /W:1 /COPYALL /ETA "F:\\" "G:\Backup\f\\"
```

If you want a mirror backup to process deletes, add the /MIR after ETA.
If you are copying to a drive that isnt NTFS, you will need /FFT as well.

Answer (score 3):

The right switch is `/XJ` (exclude junction) to only copy and unfollow symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/SL` switch.  You don't need it.

I usually just use:

```
robocopy f: G:\Backup\f\ /MIR /R:2
```

Comment: isn't the /mir for miror which will delte files in the backup e.g. sysnic the files?

Comment: /SL:: copy symbolic links versus the target.

I add this to try stop robocopy the target content I should what the shortcut

Comment: Yes, don't use /MIR unless you want a mirror copy.  The /SL is your problem.  It's following/backing up the symbolic links, which you don't want.